# Specifying consecutive file names and assigning consecutive vectors with counter variable in for loops

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze 10 sets of data, for which I have to import the data, remove some values and plot histograms. I could do it individually but can naturally save a lot of time with a for loop. I know this code is not correct, but I have no idea of how to specify the name for the input files and how to name each iterated variable in R.

```
par(mfrow = c(10,1))


for (i in 1:10)
{
  freqi <- read.delim("freqspeci.frq", sep="\t", row.names=NULL)
  freqveci <- freqi$N_CHR                                        
  freqveci <- freqveci[freqveci != 0 & freqveci != 1]             
  hist(freqveci)                                                  
}
```

What I want to do is to have the counter number in every "i" in my code. Am I just approaching this the wrong way in R? I have read about the assign and paste functions, but honestly do not understand how I can apply them properly in this particular problem.

Comment: If all you are looking for is how to parametrize each file name inside the loop, you can use e.g. `read.delim(paste0("freqspeci", i, ".frq"), sep="\t", row.names=NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do if in several ways:

1. Use `list.files()` to get all files given directory. You can use regular expression as well. [See here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html)
2. If the names are consecutive, then you can use

   ```
   for (i in 1:10)
   {
       filename <- sprintf("freqspeci.frq_%s",i)

       freqi <- read.delim(filename, sep="\t", row.names=NULL)

       freqveci <- freqi$N_CHR  

       freqveci <- freqveci[freqveci != 0 & freqveci != 1] 

       hist(freqveci)                                                  
   }
   ```
3. Use also can use `paste()` to create file name.

   ```
   paste("filename", 1:10, sep='_')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you could just save all your datafiles into an otherwise empty Folder. Then get the filenames like:

`filenames <- dir()
    for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
       freqi <- read.delim("freqspeci.frq", sep="\t", row.names=NULL)
       # and here whatever else you want to do on These files
    }`